# LDAP replication?

Tags: openldap, replication

to improve resilience, we have replicated an OpenLDAP server. There are only reading rights on the client.

After some attempts, there are no more error messages. The data part is apparently replicated correctly and the data output works. But what about the "cn=config" part? Here the schema files have been replicated but other entries only partially. For example, the local "cn = config" entry has much fewer attributes. I'm not sure what exactly should be replicated in replication.

Unfortunately, I can not find the mistake. But there are no error messages and the records are output correctly.

I would therefore like to ask again directly: must the entries in "cn=config" at the provider and the consumer by replication really match? What happens if they do not match? Here I have the entries in "cn=config" compared with the provider and the consumer:

At the provider:

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcDisallows: bind_anon
olcIdleTimeout: 600
olcLogLevel: stats2 stats none sync
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/private/osz-lise-meitner.eu.cabundle
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/private/osz-lise-meitner.eu.crt
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/osz-lise-meitner.eu.key
olcToolThreads: 1
```

At the consumer:

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcLogLevel: stats
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcToolThreads: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you replicated the `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` database? Detailed config depends on your setup, but here are some references:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212374/openldaps-cn-config-is-not-getting-fully-replicated

http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/replication.html#N-Way%20Multi-Master

http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch7/#ol-syncrepl-mm